# Date conversion using Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

How do I convert this Epoch time value returned by a JSON end point to a time string like "Tue 19 Jan 11:14:07 SGT 2038"?

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#container',

  template: '#template',

  data: {
    lastUpdated: 2147483647
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<pre>$ date --date='@2147483647' 
Tue 19 Jan 11:14:07 SGT 2038
</pre>

<div id='container'></div>
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
  <h1>Time: {{Date(lastUpdated)}}</h1>
</script>
```

I don't want to use additional libraries like moment.js. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ractive doesn't have an opinion about how to format dates, but you can very easily add a custom formatter to the `data` object:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#container',
  template: '<h1>Time: {{formatDate(lastUpdated)}}</h1>',
  data: {
    lastUpdated: 2147483647,
    formatDate: function ( date ) {
      // formatting code goes here...
    }
  }
});
```

Whenever `lastUpdated` changes, the formatter will be called again.

Comment: I was hoping to do it more inline, but I got what I wanted using your style: http://hendry.jsbin.com/bofaqa/5/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) for this:

```js
var ts = 2147483647;
var m = moment(ts);
var s = m.format("LLLL");
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#container',

  template: '#template',

  data: {
    lastUpdated: s
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/locale/af.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<pre>$ date --date='@2147483647' 
Tue 19 Jan 11:14:07 SGT 2038
</pre>

<div id='container'></div>
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
  <h1>Time: {{lastUpdated}}</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: Can I please avoid momentjs?